# I want to split text of a node and then put each of them into independent element

Tags: python, lxml, elementtree

There is a xml file like this:

sample.xml

```
<root>
    <keyword_group>
        <headword>sell/buy</headword>
    </keyword_group>
</root>
```

I'd like to split headword.text with '/' and then wrap each of them with  tag. And finally I need to remove the tag . The output I expect is:

```
<root>
    <keyword_group>
        <word>sell</word>
        <word>buy</word>
    </keyword_group>
</root>
```

My ugly script is:

```
import lxml.etree as ET

xml = '''\
<root>
    <keyword_group>
        <headword>sell/buy</headword>
    </keyword_group>
</root>
'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
headword = root.find('.//headword')
if headword is not None:
    words = headword.text.split('/')
    for word in words:
        ET.SubElement(headword, 'word')
        for wr in headword.iter('word'):
            if not wr.text:
                wr.text = word
    headword.text = ''

print(ET.tostring(root, encoding='unicode'))
```

But this is too complicated, and I failed to remove headword tags.

Comment: but your expected output isn't valid xml!

Comment: You are not using lxml in your code, but the stdlib implementation of ElementTree instead. lxml offers some more methods that the stdlib ElementTree API is missing that would help here, do you want a lxml-only answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [lxml](http://lxml.de/):

```
import lxml.etree as ET

xml = '''\
<root>
    <keyword_group>
        <headword>sell/buy</headword>
    </keyword_group>
</root>
'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
headword = root.find('.//headword')
if headword is not None:
    words = headword.text.split('/')
    parent = headword.getparent()
    parent.remove(headword)
    for word in words:
        ET.SubElement(parent, 'word').text = word

print(ET.tostring(root, encoding='unicode'))
```

yields

```
<root>
    <keyword_group>
        <word>sell</word><word>buy</word></keyword_group>
</root>
```

Comment: My answer is still sitting in draft mode waiting for the 'are you really using lxml?' comment to be answered.. May as well discard that now, it's essentially the same, bar the order of the `.remove()` and `.getparent()` calls.

Comment: It is easier to ask forgiveness than permission. :)

Comment: Yes, I'd like to use lxml if it is more convenient. Thank you so much!